# Can I use RxJS to do inter-panel communication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactive-programming, rxjs, frp

Note: I mentioned RxJS but any reactive library can do (Bacon, Kefir, Most, etc.). My context is AngularJS but the solution is probably independent (more or less).

My problem / task: we have an AngularJS application where we want to have side panels (and a central one), each side panel might have sub-panels that can be added, removed, etc.

These panels must communicate between them: not only parent-child exchanges, but also any panel to any panel (side / sub / central...).

I feel that the classical Angular way (event bus: $emit / $broadcast / $on) is rather inadequate here. Even for simple parent / child communication, I had issues, when the parent fires an event on startup, but the child isn't listening yet. Solved that with a $timeout, but that's brittle. Beside, to make two children to communicate, they send to the parent which transmits, which is clumsy.

I see this problem as an opportunity to introduce reactive programming in the project (in very early stage, won't be disruptive here), but if I have read a lot on the topic, I have little experience so far.

Hence my question: is there a clean way to manage this with FRP?

I am thinking of setting up a service (thus a singleton) which would listen to new panels, broadcast observables, accept observers, etc. But I am not too sure how to do this.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I prefer to ask if this problem has been already resolved, without too much coupling, without being inflexible, etc.

Note: if a nice solution doesn't use FRP, that's fine too! :-)

Thanks.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what others have to say. It seems to be that you are in need of a central event queue, which receives, stores and dispatch events. I say queue because you want to decouple the sender from the receiver both statically and in time. (quote "parent fires an event on startup, but the child isn't listening yet"). But then you have some sort of global variable, or inject that dependency to every function who needs it. You can have a look here (application of the event queue pattern to game programming) for inspiration : http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/event-queue.html

Comment: This is my experiment with many libraries which related FRP https://github.com/xgrommx/angular-frp/tree/gh-pages/app/frp. But I think that you need something like EventEmitter. This page can be explain about it http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/how_do_it/simple_event_emitter.html

Comment: @xgrommx : an event emitter is indeed needed. But in the implementation you mentioned (using standard subjects) I think the use case when the parent fires an event but the child does not exist yet to listen to it, is not addressed. Replacing standard subjects with `Rx.ReplaySubject` should address that. I can think of one caveat though : the events are not consumed by the first subscriber, i.e. if a second subscriber subscribes later on, it will replay the events already seen by the first subscriber. That might be the wanted behaviour or not.

Comment: I rarely ask a question because most of the time, I find answers with SO or other sources... So, when I ask a question, I don't always have a good answer... Anyway, since then I have found time to read the whole RxJS book which is excellent. And indeed, Subjects look like what I need. @xgrommx and user3743222's answers confirmed this. They should have been answers instead of comments. Well, I will make my own answer, but kudos to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @xgrommx and @user3743222's comments, and to the good RxJS book, I was able to reach my goal.

My experiment playground is at http://plnkr.co/edit/sGx4HH?p=preview

The communication center service's body is (stripped down):

```
var service = {};

service.channels = {};

/**
 * Creates a new channel with given behavior (options) and returns it.
 * If the channel already exists, just returns it.
 */
service.createChannel = function(name, behavior)
{
  checkName(name);
  if (_.isObject(service.channels[name]))
    return service.channels[name];

  behavior = behavior || {};
  _.defaults(behavior, { persistent: false });

  if (behavior.persistent)
  {
    _.defaults(behavior, { bufferSize: null /* unlimited */, windowSize: 5000 /* 5 s */ });
    service.channels[name] = new Rx.ReplaySubject(behavior.bufferSize, behavior.windowSize);
  }
  else
  {
    service.channels[name] = new Rx.Subject();
  }
  return service.channels[name];
};

/**
 * Returns the channel at given name, undefined if not existing.
 */
service.getChannel = function(name)
{
  checkName(name);
  return service.channels[name];
};

/**
 * Destroys an existing channel.
 */
service.destroyChannel = function(name)
{
  checkName(name);
  if (!_.isObject(service.channels[name]))
    return;

  service.channels[name].dispose();
  service.channels[name] = undefined;
};

/**
 * Emits an event with a value.
 */
service.emit = function(name, value)
{
  checkName(name);
  if (!_.isObject(service.channels[name]))
    return;

  service.channels[name].onNext(value);
};


function checkName(name)
{
  if (!_.isString(name))
    throw Error('Name of channel must be a string.');
}

return service;
```

I use it as follows:

```
angular.module('proofOfConceptApp', [ 'rx' ])
.run(function (CommunicationCenterService)
{
  CommunicationCenterService.createChannel('Center', { persistent: true });
  CommunicationCenterService.createChannel('Left');
  CommunicationCenterService.createChannel('Right');
})
.controller('CentralController', function ($scope, $http, rx, observeOnScope, CommunicationCenterService) 
{
  var vm = this;

  CommunicationCenterService.getChannel('Right')
    .safeApply($scope, function (color) 
    {
      vm.userInput = color;
    })
    .subscribe();

  observeOnScope($scope, function () { return vm.userInput; })
    .debounce(1000)
    .map(function(change)
    {
      return change.newValue || "";
    })
    .distinctUntilChanged() // Only if the value has changed
    .flatMapLatest(searchWikipedia)
    .safeApply($scope, function (result) 
    {
      // result: [0] = search term, [1] = found names, [2] = descriptions, [3] = links
      var grouped = _.zip(result.data[1], result.data[3]);
      vm.results = _.map(grouped, function(r)
      {
        return { title: r[0], url: r[1] };
      });
      CommunicationCenterService.emit('Center', vm.results.length);
    })
    .subscribe();

  function searchWikipedia(term) 
  {
    console.log('search ' + term);
    return rx.Observable.fromPromise($http(
      {
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK",
        method: "jsonp",
        params: 
        {
          action: "opensearch",
          search: encodeURI(term),
          format: "json"
        }
      }));             
  }

  CommunicationCenterService.emit('Center', 42); // Emits immediately
})
.controller('SubController', function($scope, $http, rx, observeOnScope, CommunicationCenterService) 
{
  var vm = this;

  vm.itemNb = $scope.$parent.results;//.length;

  CommunicationCenterService.getChannel('Left')
    .safeApply($scope, function (toggle) 
    {
      vm.messageFromLeft = toggle ? 'Left is OK' : 'Left is KO';
    })
    .subscribe();

  CommunicationCenterService.getChannel('Center')
    .safeApply($scope, function (length) 
    {
      vm.itemNb = length;
    })
    .subscribe();
})
.controller('LeftController', function($scope, $http, rx, observeOnScope, CommunicationCenterService) 
{
  var vm = this;

  vm.toggle = true;

  vm.toggleValue = function ()
  {
    CommunicationCenterService.emit('Left', vm.toggle);
  };

  observeOnScope($scope, function () { return vm.toggle; })
    .safeApply($scope, function (toggleChange) 
    {
      vm.valueToDisplay = toggleChange.newValue ? 'On' : 'Off';
    })
    .subscribe();

  CommunicationCenterService.getChannel('Center')
    .safeApply($scope, function (length) 
    {
      vm.messageFromCenter = 'Search gave ' + length + ' results';
    })
    .subscribe();
})
.controller('RightController', function($scope, $http, rx, observeOnScope, CommunicationCenterService) 
{
  var vm = this;

  var display = { red: 'Pink', green: 'Aquamarine', blue: 'Sky' };

  vm.color = { value: "blue" }; // Initial value

  observeOnScope($scope, function () { return vm.color.value; })
    .tap(function(x) 
    { 
      CommunicationCenterService.emit('Right', vm.color.value);
    })
    .safeApply($scope, function (colorChange) 
    {
      vm.valueToDisplay = display[colorChange.newValue];
    })
    .subscribe();

  CommunicationCenterService.getChannel('Left')
    .safeApply($scope, function (toggle) 
    {
      vm.messageFromLeft = toggle ? 'Left is on' : 'Left is off';
    })
    .subscribe();
})
;
```

I have to create the channels upfront (in .run) otherwise listening to an uncreated channel crashes. Not sure if I will lift the restriction...

It is only a rough draft, probably brittle, but it reaches my expectations so far.

I hope it can be useful to somebody.

[EDIT] I updated my plunk.

In Take 2: http://plnkr.co/edit/0yZ86a I cleaned up the API and made an intermediary service hiding the channel service. Channels are created upfront. I made clean up of subscriptions a bit easier.

In Take 3: http://plnkr.co/edit/UqdyB2 I adds topics to channels (inspired by Postal.js) allowing finer communication and less Subjects.